# Response PHP is empty

Tags: php, jquery

I use jquery to call two url in file indexFunctions.php but the response of server is empty i dont know why please help there is my code

```
$("#start_peering").submit(function(event){
    $("#wait").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif">');
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
            url : 'indexFunctions.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {peering:true},
            success : function(data){
                    $("#StbStatus").html(data);
                    $.ajax({
                            url : 'indexFunctions.php',
                            type : 'POST',
                            data : {test_params:true},
                            success : function(data){
                                    $("#results").html(data);
                                    $("#wait").html('');
                                    }
                             });


            }
    });

});
```

File indexFunctions.php

```
$rpi="http://192.168.1.15";

  if (isset($_POST['peering']) && isset($_POST['test_params']))
{   
  $url = $rpi."/peering.php?askSTB=true";
  $response = proxy::get($url);
  echo $response;   
  $url = $rpi."/installUSBKeyOnStb.php";
  $response = proxy::get($url);
  echo $response;

 }

 ?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see you setting *both* `peering` and `test_params` at the same time, which is what your `if` statement is checking.

Comment: what's in `$repsonce` variable? it may be you can debug yourself without StackOverflow?

Comment: Your PHP checks the presence of __both__ `peering` and `test_params` in `$_POST` but your Ajax call just sends `{peering: true}`, so your PHP condition is false, so there's no `echo $response`.

Comment: Others pointed out that your if always returns false because both post values are not set in the first call, but really your code is just logically wrong. You should separate it into two different calls, and return values accordingly.

Comment: @JordiNebot, I share the same opinion. But at the same time, it's counted to be off-topic on this website, as it belongs to category of **trivial debugging** of questions alike "*why my code is not working.*". I vote for off-topic.

Comment: @JordiNebot thank you for your answer i have understand

Comment: @Farside, honestly I can't say if it's off-topic. [Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) say _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._

Comment: @JordiNebot, let's assume you are right. What's the value of this "debugging help" question with logical erro to the other community members? What people would be searching to get in here? There are thousands of such questions, and it can be easily marked as duplicate as well. I given my vote anyways. But at the same time, this is good community helped out the OP with his question!

Comment: @Farside, I can't be right nor wrong because I just said _I can't say_ and quoted help. Anyway I guess this isn't the place for this discussion, so let's focus helping OP and/or let the community do their job :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be sending two request but checking if both are set at the same time.

```
if (isset($_POST['peering']) && isset($_POST['test_params']))
```

You should check for either or not both.

Try changing it to:

```
if (isset($_POST['peering']) || isset($_POST['test_params']))
```

Comment: but it could be same way the error in the logic of the request itself as well :) so it's just the logical bomb which has to be solved

Comment: @Farside yes it could be errors somewhere else, but from the code i see the IF statement is the only error/problem i can see.

Comment: the code has logical mistakes, it can be anything, as the purpose is not clear from OP.

Comment: @Farside yes but from the question it is asking why there is no response, and my answer is the reason why. It will never get to the echo part because its checking for both, not one or the other.

Answer (score -1):

You used AND && instead of OR ||

Comment: It's not a full-fledged answer, really, use **comments** next time.

Comment: @Farside No, this is an attempt to answer the question. It belongs as an answer.